# filtering python list comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am working through some tutorial exercises learning about python comprehensions. I came across one that asks to build a comprehension that returns a 3-tuple of all combinations of numbers in a given set that sum to zero--excluding the trivial example of (0,0,0).

I came up with this:

```
def tupleNonTrivialSumation(s):
    '''return a 3-tuple of x,y,z : x+y+z=0 & the list does not contain (0,0,0)'''
    return tuple([(x,y,z) for x in s for y in s for z in s if x+y+z==0 if abs(x)+abs(y)+abs(z)!=0])`
```

is there a more concise way to write this? it seems like there should be a better way to check if x,y,z sum to zero.

Answer (score 4):

If the order is important you can use `itertools.permutation()`:

```
from itertools import permutation
[sub for sub in permutation(s, 3) if sum(sub) == 0 and sub != (0, 0, 0)]
```

Otherwise use `itertools.combinations()`

Comment: `[...if sum(sub) == 0 and sub != (0, 0, 0)]`?  Don't you need to exclude "the trivial example of (0,0,0)"?

Comment: @Alexander Yes, sure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need all the *combinations* not *permutations* as you need to `sum` them.

```
import itertools
cs = itertools.combinations(sequence, 3)
result = [c for c in cs if sum(c) == 0 and any(c)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Following the "Zen of Python", I would just make a simple change to the filter condition:

```
[(x, y, z) for x in s for y in s for z in s if x + y + z == 0 and (x, y, z) != (0, 0, 0)]
```